# Change display type of zipcode/postcode

Tags: zipcode

Currently the zipcode inside Magento is displayed as 1234AB in the backend (orders).

I want to change this to 1234 AB, with a space between the numbers and letters.

I already checked the template options, but it is loaded as `{{var postcode}}`.

How can I change that?